# Fetch null values from JSON response

Tags: java, json, rest, rest-assured

I have extracted the JSON response from API using rest assured and it looks something like this :

```
[
{
"firstKey": ["value1", "value2"],
"secondKey": 4,
"thirdValue": "value3",
"fourthValue":"value4"
},
{
"firstKey": ["value5", "value6"],
"secondKey": 5,
"thirdValue": "value7",
"fourthValue":"value8"
}
]
```

Now, my actual JSON response would have thousand of JSON Objects inside the JSON array, and some of the keys would have null values, for eg. "secondKey" would have null values in some JSON Object. 
I need to fetch all the keys which have null values in the JSON response. Any thoughts on how can I do this ?

My idea to solve this one was to deserialize JSON using Jackson library and fetching all the null values. However, is there any efficient solution considering performance ?

Comment: What have u done so far? one way to solve this is, to use the Gson library from google. Then you can map the Json to a Map and you can go on with the map and filter the null values.

Comment: I was thinking of deserializing JSON using Jackson lib. However, I am worried about the performance when my response would have 10,000 json objects

Comment: Assuming each JSON object key is returned in the response even when it's value is null, you can try to use a regex pattern to extract the key that has a null value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using JavaScript and your null values look like this `"secondKey": null;`

Here is a way to fetch those keys:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(json_array); // json_array is your json response
var nullKeys = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    var obj = arr[i];
    for (var key in obj)
        if(obj[key] == null) 
            nullKeys.push(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex pattern with group matcher to extract the keys with `null` value.

```
    String pattern = "\"(.*)\": null";
    String json = "[\n" +
            "{\n" +
            "\"firstKey\": [\"value1\", \"value2\"],\n" +
            "\"secondKey\": null,\n" +
            "\"thirdValue\": null,\n" +
            "\"fourthValue\":\"value4\"\n" +
            "},\n" +
            "{\n" +
            "\"firstKey\": [\"value5\", \"value6\"],\n" +
            "\"secondKey\": null,\n" +
            "\"thirdValue\": \"value7\",\n" +
            "\"fourthValue\":\"value8\"\n" +
            "}\n" +
            "]";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(json);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Following is the output

```
secondKey
thirdValue
secondKey
```

Answer (score 0):

You partly answered yourself - one of the most efficient ways actually *is* to use the Jackson library. In this case you use its [Streaming API](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonStreamingApi) for efficiently parsing the input JSON string.

Here is an example of how to output all the keys will null values, no matter where in the JSON structure they are located:

```java
JsonParser parser = new JsonFactory().createParser(json);

while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
    if (parser.currentToken() == JsonToken.VALUE_NULL) {
        System.out.println("Got null in key: " + parser.currentName());
    }
}
```

Note that this will also output `Got null in key: null` if there is a `null` in an array. Here is a somewhat more complicated code which tries to cope with this:

```java
JsonParser parser = new JsonFactory().createParser(content);

Stack<String> nestedArrays = new Stack<String>();
while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
    // note: a switch could be used as well
    if (parser.currentToken() == JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
        // note: a top level array returns `null` here
        nestedArrays.push(parser.currentName());
    }
    if (parser.currentToken() == JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
        nestedArrays.pop();
    }
    if (parser.currentToken() == JsonToken.VALUE_NULL) {
        String key = parser.currentName();
        if (key == null) {
            key = nestedArrays.lastElement();
        }
        System.out.println("Got null in key / array: " + key);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is working beautifully for all the json keys except those which have there values as arrays for eg. if firstKey from above json has one null value inside the array, it prints key(parser.currentName())as null. Any idea on that ?

Comment: yes, so it is as I write in my last sentence, isn't it? It depends on what you want to do in this case. You either just skip this - don't add the `null` to your resulting list of keys. If your intention is to know the key under which the array with a null item is stored, this is surely also doable - do you need this? It isn't quite clear from the OP, I think.

Comment: apologies, totally missed your last statement. Any idea on how can I find the key name under which an array has a null  ?

Comment: that's ok. I extended my answer so that it hopefully copes with this as well. I think it could be sufficient as an answer... :)